# My SocketIO script is always sending the same data

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io

I have this Python variable called tst, which is equal to `2`. I want to send the value of this variable to my frontend to my frontend using SocketIO.

The code is working, the only problem is that instead of storing a single `two` in my javascript array, it will keep filling the array with `2` each time an update is sent. The javascript array should look like this `[2]` (i will be sending other values, this is just a test), but instead it looks like this

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ........ 2]
```

Is there a way to fix this?

SocketIO:

```
 class RandomThread(Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            self.delay = 1
            super(RandomThread, self).__init__()

        def randomNumberGenerator(self):
            """
            Generate a random number every 1 second and emit to a socketio instance (broadcast)
            Ideally to be run in a separate thread?
            """
            #infinite loop of magical random numbers
            print("Making random numbers")
            while not thread_stop_event.isSet():
                number = round(random()*10, 3)

                tst = 2

                print(number)
                socketio.emit('newnumber', {'number': number}, namespace='/test')

                socketio.emit('two', {'num': tst}, namespace='/test')

                sleep(self.delay)



        def run(self):
            self.randomNumberGenerator()
```

application.js

```
socket.on('two', function(msg) {
console.log("Received" + msg.num);

arr.push(msg.num)

console.log(arr);
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what `.push()` does. What behavior did you expect in details?

Comment: Well, i only want to have 2 one time, in the future i will have some data each second instead of that "2", and i want to have only new data. This way, it will keep printing the same data over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is being filled because your Python code sends those 2's in a loop and your client code appends ([pushes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) it to the array. You have to clear the array or define it in the function scope. However I don't know why do you want a single number in an array as a result. If you want a single random number from the server every second, one variable is enough. On the other hand, if you need array of random numbers, it would be better to prepare it on the server side and then send the whole thing through socket. I have a feeling that's the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Let me explain it further: in the future, intead of that "2" i will have some other numbers to push to my Javascript frontend. Those numbers pushed on the frontend will be charted in real time with a Javascript charting library. The problem is that, with this situation, it will keep sending the same data over and over again, when i'll want to have only NEW data

Comment: It doesn't send the same data. I mean it does, but only because you told it so send  "2".  If those numbers were random, it should work like you want it to work. 
Unless you want to send more specific data than random numbers. Then it's up to your server to generate this data and send it. Perhaps your thread can quit by itself after it sends the data, instead of being notified by an event.

Comment: I just checked and for some reason it seems to send the same number 4 times.

Comment: I debugged it with a console.log(arr) and i noticed that the same number seemed to be added to the array multiple times

Comment: I can only make guesses. Maybe you your random function returns a number twice in a row, it's perfectly possible.
Do you have multiple threads running? I don't think random() is thread safe.

Comment: Think i solved the problem, it was my JS endpoint being placed at the wrong place. What do you mean with 'thread safe'?

Comment: Glad to hear that. About thread safety - threads can introduce data races and undefined behaviour. I recommend you to do some reading, its complicated subject